# Delete quotation marks from a variable

Tags: bash, text-processing

I've got a variable string value which looks like:
`webenv1="value",`

My question is, how can I delete the quotation marks and comma from this variable value to permanently change the value?

Comment: What quotations marks and comma?  Will more context to answer this question.

Comment: Sorry, the variable value literally looks like "abcdefg", . I'm looking to convert to abcdefg

Comment: Yes but looks like that where?  In a script file?  When you echo it in the shell?  What?  Please, more context.

Comment: Ah ok. That would be when I echo it in the shell yeah.

Comment: Using [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion): `echo "${var//\"/}" `...

Comment: brilliant! So lets say I want to permanently change the value in that variable to lose quotation marks, what would I need to change?

Comment: `webenv1="${webenv1//\"}"`

Comment: that done it! thank you assorted internet sorcerers

Answer (score 2):

Re-set the variable using [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) with removing of all double quotes:

```
webenv1="${webenv1//\"}"
```

And to remove both quotes and comma:

```
webenv1="${webenv1//[\",]}"
```

To remove *only* the leading quote and the trailing-quote-and-comma:

```
webenvtemp=${webenv1#\"}
webenv1=${webenvtemp%\",}
```

To use the bash-specific `=~` conditional construct to do it:

```
[[ "$webenv1" =~ "(.+)", ]]
webenv1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```